# Intellij no longer showing "Resolve Conflicts" dialog?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have routinely used the (excellent) Intellij/Pycharm "Resolve Conflicts" available by right clicking in any source file in the project and accessing from the "Git" submenu.  However the Git menu no longer shows it:

[image]

We can confirm that `git` is an "unresolved conflict" state by running `git status` that returns

> fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.

This has happened several times in different git repos now.  I am on `Intellij Ultimate 20.2`.

*Update*  I just installed  latest `Intellij Ultimate 20.3`: same issue.

Comment: Please see: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now buried under a submenu. From @RuslanKuleshov (Jetbrains employee):

[image]

The issue is here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257569 ,

Answer (score 3):

You can always switch to Commit in the left column and click on resolve there:

[image: commit thingy with resolve option]